# How to get total number of packages in pypi?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

```
pip list  --format=columns |wc -l
73
```

It shows that 73 packages installed on my local pc.
How to get total number of packages in pypi remote official server?

Comment: see also https://libraries.io/platforms and http://www.modulecounts.com/ for multi-language statistics on the number of packages.

Answer (score 3):

What about parsing [PyPI's official webpage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)? If you'd like to do so, we can use `requests` package to get the content of the page and extract the content we want using `BeautifulSoup` package from the page like this.

This is [the content](https://screencast.com/t/1TjvAhWR) that are extracting. We'll need to install `requests` and `beautifulsoup4` packages if you haven't already.

```
pip install requests
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Request and parse:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://pypi.python.org/pypi")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select('div.section > p > strong')[0].get_text())
```